# pg_dump significant size difference between dumps

Tags: postgresql, backup, windows, compression

So we've been doing some temporary backups on windows machines and came across something interesting.

Doing plain formatted dumps with no compression and blobs,
we get significant size differences between the two dumps from the same DB.

- With redirect `>>`: 1.169.048 KB
- With the `-f` option: ** 584.460 KB**

Does anybody know what happens in the background that could cause this?

Is it an encoding thing?

I'm kind of intrigued by what could cause such a difference.

Comment: I don't know if it's a Windows problem, or the way the Postgres tools work with "stdout" and "stdin", but I found that redirection doesn't work properly on Windows with them.

Comment: `>>` appends to an existing file. So maybe you didn't delete the old backup when you tried with `>>`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Just did a double check to make sure. It produces the same result with brand new files.